# Как лучше обработать первую итерацию цикла?

Tags: python, ооп

```py
class MyClass:
    response = None 

    def run_handler(self):
        self.response = get_response()

    def set_response(self):
        self.run_handler()
        while self.response.status is not 'ok':
            self.run_handler()
```

Как можно улучшить это код, чтобы не повторять `run_handler` вне цикла? На первой итерации у объекта `response` еще нет свойства status.

Comment: Прямо ваш пример в вики питона https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop

Comment: @AlexeyTen да, спасибо, это вариант)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for

```
class MyClass:
    response = None

    def run_handler(self, _):
        self.response = get_response()
        return self.response.status

    def set_response(self, retry=10):
        for status in map(self.run_handler, range(retry)):
            if status == 'ok':
                break
        else:
            print('status FAIL')
```

while

```
class MyClass:
    response = None

    def run_handler(self):
        self.response = get_response()
        return self.response.status != 'ok'

    def set_response(self):
        while self.run_handler(): continue
```

iter

```
class MyClass:
    response = None

    def run_handler(self):
        self.response = get_response()

def set_response(self):
    it = iter(self.run_handler, object())
    while next(it) or self.response.status != 'ok': continue
```

рекурсия

```
class MyClass:
    response = None

    def run_handler(self):
        self.response = get_response()

    def set_response(self):
        self.run_handler()
        if self.response.status != 'ok':
            self.set_response()
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну, я бы не сказал, что этот вариант плох. Он нормально читается, вполне лаконичен и, кажется, все попытки его как-то "улучшить" вряд ли уменьшат количество кода.

Но, если очень хочется, то можно так сделать:

```
class MyClass:
    response = None
    status = 'not_requested_yet'

    def run_handler(self):
        self.response = get_response()
        self.status = self.response.status

    def set_response(self):
        while self.status != 'ok':
            self.run_handler()
```

Comment: Вопрос, конечно, решает, но делает код запутаннее :) Выше предложили делать бесконечный цикл и прерывать по выполнению условия.